# SQLite function calls all have invalid arguments

Tags: c++, eclipse, sqlite, invalid-argument

I'm trying to add the SQLite Amalgamation to my project. According to [their page](http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html), I "Just copy the amalgamation into your source directory and compile it along with the other C code files in your project." I've also copied in sqlite3.h so I have access to the API.

However, any function call to the API, for instance:

```
sqlite3 *db;
int rc;

rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
```

results in the following error:

> Invalid arguments '
>   Candidates are:
>   int sqlite3_open(const char *, * *) '
>
> DataSettings.cpp
>   /FCS/src
>   line 24
>   Semantic Error

What am I doing wrong here? What have I neglected to set up?

Comment: Please show the *complete* and *unedited* error output.

Comment: You have tagged the question C++.  This is a different language from C, in which sqlite is implemented.  I am uncertain whether the amalgamation will be correctly built by a C++ compiler, but it looks like you probably have a difference in name mangling (which would imply "no").  You might be able to solve the problem by appropriate placement of one or more `extern "C" { }` blocks in the amalgamation source file, and possibly also in the header.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Error is copy and pasted out of Eclipse. Only edit was to remove the file name, path, and line number. But I'll edit to include those.

Comment: @JohnBollinger This is already included in the amalgamation. In the header file is:`#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif`

Comment: The header and compiled implementation must match, and the signs point to that not being the case for you.  The amalgamation's C source file must declare all functions with external linkage to have `extern "C"` linkage in particular, or else you must compile with a C compiler (perhaps you can pass an option to your compiler to make it do that).  It is not sufficient for the C source file to include the sqlite header if you are compiling it as C++ source.

Comment: It would be best all around to compile the C source with a C compiler, rather than with a C++ compiler.  Alternatively, link a pre-built external (possibly shared) library, instead of building the amalgamation.

Comment: This might be a problem with the header. Show a *minimal* but *complete* program.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I ended up building the amalgamation as a separate C project and then linking it in as a library. I used a static library instead of shared because I am more concerned with run-time performance than size but this was the solution. If you add your comment as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has the hallmarks of a name-mangling mismatch.  Because C++ allows functions to be overloaded based on their argument types, C++ compilers must "mangle" function names they emit into object code to encode the argument types.  C compilers do not do this, and do not expect it to be done to them.  Specifying to a C++ compiler that a function has "C" linkage disables name mangling AND overloading of that function name; this is what `extern "C"` does.

Although C is similar in many ways to a subset of C++, the two are distinct languages.  It is best to compile C code with a C compiler.  One of your alternatives, therefore, is to build the C source of the sqlite amalgamation separately from your C++ code, into a library for instance, and link that with your C++ object files to produce the final executable.